# Probability density function for other norm? ($\ell_2$ norm is normal distribution)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

For a vector, we know that the standard normal distribution has pdf:$$f(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp(-\frac{||x-\mu||_2^2}2),$$

which depends on the $\ell_2$ norm $||x-\mu||_2^2$. Can we have other pdfs which have the similar form but depend on other norms like $\ell_1$ and $\ell_\infty$?

Comment: For any norm $e^{-\|x\|}$ is integrable and some constant multiple of it is a density function. But I don't think these are used in any applications.

Comment: You often see them introduced as a regularisation term in an optimisation problem, and then as the prior for which the log-likelihood would look like the cost function of the corresponding optimisation problem

Comment: If I understand the spirit of your question correctly, what you are after are the stable distributions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_stable_distribution. In fact, something very special happens for the exponent $p=2$ corresponding to the Gaussian, related to the fact that the Gaussian equals its own Fourier transform. In general, the correct generalization from $\ell_2$ to $\ell_p$ is related to the Fourier transform of the distribution (i.e. the characteristic function). There is also a nice characterization in terms of infinite divisibility (see link above).